# How to load balance requests using header value in IBM web server plugin?

Tags: websphere, ibm-was

We are using IBM Web Server plugin to load balance in a cluster of web servers. So far we are routing the requests based on URLs. We now need to route a set of requests using combination of URL and a header value. How can this be done?

Comment: The question is for Server Fault.

Comment: How can I move a question there?

Comment: The question here will be closed if community decides that it is off-topic. You need to post a new one on SF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot -- the WAS WebServer Plugin only considers the host, URL, and session affinity.  Are you trying to select an alternate cluster, or just a specific backend server?

Either way, the only viable option is to manipulate the URL or session cookie and use the normal routing.